# Page to page fading effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, transition

i need to implement load/unload page animations fade-in on load, and fade-out on unload.

1) I have read some articles about implementation it based on links clicks. That's does not work for me. I don't want to go that way, because some links should not open new page actually, and have href.

So imagine: link has properly href, but sometimes it open new page, sometimes not, based on it  handler behavior. We add another handler that fire redirect all the time as timeout callback.

2) I can't implement animation using page unload event. I think it's right way.

Please help or advice something. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was finding the way without using links event, but using any UNLOAD event. Links events can be used only on a small website. In my case it created additional errors. For example some links, shouldn't do fade-out, and i don't know which of them actually.

So i don't recommend to do this. Need to find any UNLOAD page redirections animation way.

Answer (score 0):

Give your links you want to animate a class. Then you can use the `.click()` method to check when a link is clicked. Then do a preventDefault to stop the default behavior.
The next thing to do is check if there is "http" in the href attribute. You can get the value with `$(this).attr('href');`. If the link contains this, you need to go to a new page. For this, use `window.location.href`. Call this method as the callback of your `fadeOut()`.

The only thing that is left is do a fade in when the page loads ;)

Comment: Imagine that some link has href and also other click event, this event handler sometimes should open new window using it's link href, sometimes not :) 

Actually i don't know which link should open new window. 

So i'm finding original implementation using window.unload

Comment: @Rantiev: Can you set an extra data attribute in your link and if that data attribute is set you do something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly..
Put this code in the pages' <head>s.

```
<style>
    @keyframes page_transition
    {   
        from {opacity: 0;}
        to {opacity: 1;}
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes page_transition
    {
        from {opacity: 0;}
        to {opacity: 1;}
    }
    html
    {
        animation: page_transition 1s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-animation: page_transition 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    html.unloading
    {
        transition: opacity 500ms linear !important;
        opacity: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
            document.documentElement.classList.add("unloading");
        });
</script>
```